# JQuery Validation revalidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the JQuery Validation fine but I need to somehow re-validate a field. I have a text field that has a remote aspect and that works fine. However, there is a select box above it that may change. I just want the validation to happen again if the value of the select box changes. Is that possible?

```
$('#input').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                dbname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    onKeyUp: false,
                    remote: {
                        type:"post",
                        url:'createdb/checkdbname',
                        data: {
                            catserver: function(){
                                return $("#catserver").val();
                            },
                            prepend: function(){
                                return $("#prepend").text();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                },
                dataname: {
                    required: true
                },
                clientsel: {
                    required: true
                }

            },

            messages: {
                dbname: {
                    remote: "Database Already Exists on Server"

                }
            },
```

Basically the select box catserver and dbname kinda depend on each other. I'm not sure if i'm handling this correctly. I'm using bootstrap for the form with codeigniter if that matters. Basically what happens is after I validate fine and someone changes the select value of catserver the validation of the dbname doesn't happen again unless I change the value of the dbname field.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can bind the *change* event to the element that should trigger your validation:

```
$('.my-select-box').on('change', validate);

function validate() {
   $('#input').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                dbname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    onKeyUp: false,
                    remote: {
                        type:"post",
                        url:'createdb/checkdbname',
                        data: {
                            catserver: function(){
                                return $("#catserver").val();
                            },
                            prepend: function(){
                                return $("#prepend").text();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                },
                dataname: {
                    required: true
                },
                clientsel: {
                    required: true
                }

            },

            messages: {
                dbname: {
                    remote: "Database Already Exists on Server"

                }
            },
// .......
}
```